# VBa vlookup , replace range as variable

Tags: excel, vba, formula, vlookup

OK I will reformulate the question.

I have a worksheet with a tab named"My INT".
This tab contains a data table and a button with an assigned macro called "importRMR". code below:

```
Sub importRMR()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("G3")
Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet).Name = "RMR " & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YY")
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(966.75, 27.75, 153.75, 125.25).Select
Selection.OnAction = "Cimp"

Selection.Characters.Text = "Importuj"
With Selection.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=13).Font
    .Name = "Tahoma"
    .FontStyle = "Standaard"
    .Size = 16
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    End With
End Sub
```

This creates a tab with a specific name :RMR " & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YY")

NOw I manually paste the table( always identical ) to the newly created tab "RMR 03/08/2018". the next step is to click the button in this tab ( Importuj) and the  result I am aiming for is to :
1. Vlookup data in tab "my INT" where the range( lookup array) is tab "RMR" and then delete the rmr tab.

such procedures like triming the data pasting values and so on I am able to do, just the vlookup but is a problem.

my current code for "importuj " button is:
ub TEST()

```
Dim DOTR As String

Dim shT As String
Set shT = Sheets(DOTR).Range("E2:H584")




'shT = Sheets(DOTR).Range("c1:e2").Select






DOTR = "RMR " & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YY")
'Sheets(DOTR).Range ("E2:H584").selc


Worksheets("My INT").Range("N3").Formula = "=vlookup(c3,sht,3,0)"


End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I get an error - "Compile Error" - Object required.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: haha SORRY, ADDED THE CODE NOW :)

Comment: So what I am trying to do: 1

Answer (score 2):

The goal is to combine several different strings into a one cohesive string:

```
=VLOOKUP(C3,'ABCDEF 03-08-18'!$B$4:$D$10,3,0)
```

That will be placed inside a cell using:

```
Worksheet.Range.Formula
```

The worksheet name "ABCDEF" is arbitrary and we create the date on the fly.  We use a named range in Excel "myNamedRange" and reference the address property to allow flexibility without editing code.

```
Dim strSheetName As String
Dim strNamedRange As String
Dim strDateSegment As String
Dim strPrefix As String
Dim shT As String

strSheetName = "My INT"
strNamedRange = "myNamedRange"
strDateSegment = Format(Day(Date), "00") & "-" & Format(Month(Date), "00") & "-" & Right(Year(Date), 2) & "'!"
strPrefix = "'" & "ABCDEF"

shT = "=VLOOKUP(C3," & strPrefix & strDateSegment & Worksheets(strSheetName).Range(strNamedRange).Address & ",3,0)"

Worksheets("My INT").Range("N3").Formula = shT
```

Comment: figures sht is a string  ...  set has nothing to do with it

Comment: I want the sht to be the range in newlly created tab DOTR = "RMR " & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YY")

Comment: ahhhh.... finally, you added some detail.  at the cost of my soon to be non-existent rep.  taking a look.

Comment: Well I basically want to place a formula in a range, it doesn't has to be the cell, I just thought that if I place it in a cell I can easily amend it and write a code to fill the rest of the column until the end of the table with this formula and then copy paste as values.  The conet of the cells (sht) is product names ( 1 column) and different number values in the adjactent columns.

Comment: ok.  we'll go with it.  starting with the imediate error, remove set from Set shT = Sheets(DOTR).Range("E2:H584"), while you're at it, consider that you have a vba variable inside quotes for your vlookup, this is a nogo, can't do it like that.  it has to be wrapped up in a larger string.. something like str = "=vlookup(c3," & sht & ",3,0)"   then your worksheet.range.formula=str

Comment: is this what you want your vlookup to look like in the spreadsheet?  "=vlookup(c3, E2:H584,3,0)"

Comment: Well not exactly I need it to look like that: =VLOOKUP(C3,'RMSSS 03-08-18'!$D$2:$H$7,4,0), The,"'RMSSS 03-08-18'!" is troublesome.

Comment: OK I feel Like it is lamost it:

Comment: Just the range name in the formula is still not right. instead of 'RMSSS 03-08-18'!D1:H9 the range is D1:H9

Comment: strSheetName = "RMR " & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YY")
strNamedRange = "c1:d45"

shT = "=VLOOKUP(C3," & Worksheets(strSheetName).Range(strNamedRange).Address & ",4,0)"

Comment: Usually complaining about downvotes results in even more downvotes. Sad but true...

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious I downvoted the answer because its first few iterations were pretty much only a comment, while I appreciate the effort you've shown it would desirable if you kept your answers and comments professional. I'm sure that if you toned down the sass and used comments when they're needed, your answer would be a lot more popular.

Comment: Worksheetys(strSheetname) doeesnt work correctlly. the ouput is not 'RMSSS 03-08-18'!$D$2 butjust the range. Weird since strSheetName = "RMR " & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YY"),I belive gives the correct output

Comment: My Mistake!  I'd neglected to wrap our new name up like a worksheet!

Comment: To explain specifically, strPrefix = "'" & "RMR ", i added an apostrophe, shT = "=VLOOKUP(C3," & strPrefix & strDateSegment & "!" & Worksheets  .... I added an exclamation point, and  lastly (Date), "00") & "-" & Right(Year(Date), 2) & "'"    I added another apostrophe

Comment: That creates the   '      '! that encloses the worksheet name.  If you're confused, go to any vlookup you have currently in Excel that references a different sheet and look for the beginning apostrophe and the end apostrophe followed immediately by the exclamation point

Comment: Well, still got a script out of range error, at the last line of code. BUT I do see how you wanna tackle it, will try to fiddle with it, maybe I will succeed. Anyway Thank you very much for your time   ProfoundlyOblivious , I greatlly appreciate  your help.

Comment: if you're getting an out of range error, there's something driving it that isn't related to what we've covered.  I have to pretend like i'm a working man for the next 9 hours.  maybe someone will pick this up.  but what we've created thus far should be solid and error free